# How can i display form success message on same { div } without refreshing the page?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, form-submit

How can I submit a form on same  without refreshing page? Here I'm submitting a pdf to drag and drop container and when I submit the form it's redirecting to upload.php. I need to display the successful message on the same container . I have not enough knowledge about the ajax. Kindly please help me to solve the issue

Here is the drag and drop container below:

[image]

Here is the result page **(upload.php)** below:

[image]

**HTML Form:**

```
<form method="POST" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" multiple name="file[]" accept="application/pdf">
      <input class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Upload.php file:**

```
<?php 
//echo 'done';
$output = '';

    if(isset($_FILES['file']['name'][0])){
        //echo 'ok';
        foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $keys => $values) {

            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$keys], 'upload/' .$values)) {

                $output .= 'Form submited succesfully';
            }
        }
    }
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: You can prevent for submit by using event.preventdefault and manually send the form data over api. This will prevent the page from being refreshed.

Comment: Here is the good example of file uploading usign jquery / ajax try this.. https://www.roytuts.com/ajax-file-upload-using-php-jquery/

Comment: Ajax should do the job : don't sub your form but add a "on click" event on your form button, so when user will click submit you will stay on same page and use Ajax to do the sumbit part, then on your "success" part you display what you want on current page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the default behaviour of the form on submit, which redirects it.
Try using this:

```
<form id="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id='file' type="file" multiple name="file[]" accept="application/pdf">
  <input class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<p id="response-text"></p>
    <script>
        $("#form").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append("file", document.getElementById("file").files[0]);
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("response-text").innerHTML = 'Form Successfully Submitted';
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("response-text").innerHTML = 'Form could not be submitted';
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("post", "/upload.php", true);
            xhttp.send(data);
        });

    </script>
```

Now you can display the desired message wherever you want to display. Here I have displayed on `<p>` of id `response-text`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input id='file' type="file" multiple name="file[]" accept="application/pdf">
            <input id='submit'class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

```
 $("#submit").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          var data = new FormData();

          data.append("file",document.getElementById("file").files[0]);
          xhr.open("post","/upload.php",true);

          xhr.send(data);


            });
```

Comment: Not working Fadi, Still, it's redirecting to upload.php

Comment: It seems that the `submit` handler should be bound to the `<form>` instead of the `<input>`. The `submit` event "can only be attached to `<form>` elements" 
 -- [submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Comment: This may not be a good option, but you can change the submit button to a normal button with an onclick tag that calls the following javascript function ```var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          var data = new FormData();

          data.append("file",document.getElementById("file").files[0]);
          xhr.open("post","/upload.php",true);

          xhr.send(data);
 ```